# jQuery cloned div not reacting on hover function

Tags: jquery, drupal, clone

I am working with a CMS, so I do not have full control on what get displayed in which manner, so I decided to simply clone a  container, using the code below. Clone gets created as expected, but as you can see in my script (first rows) I want to have a hover effect on it. On the original  it works like expected, but the cloned section does not react on the hover function, why is this? How could I get around it?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("section.block-bookoblock").hover(function(){
    $(".block-bookoblock ul.menu").css("display","block");
    },function(){
    $(".block-bookoblock ul.menu").css("display","none");
  });
  document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};
  $('#page:not(#newid)').mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.button == 2 ) { 
    if ($('#newid').length) {
    $('#newid').css({ "display": 'block'});
    $('#newid').css({ "top": e.pageY +'px'});
    $('#newid').css({ "left": e.pageX +'px'});
        } else {
    var $div = $('#block-bookoblock-book-outline').clone().attr('id','newid');   
    $('body').append($div); 
      $('#newid').css({ "top": e.pageY +'px'});
      $('#newid').css({ "left": e.pageX +'px'});
      $('#newid').css({ "position": 'absolute'});
      return false; 
    } 
    }
    if( e.button == 0 ) {
    $('#newid').css({ "display": 'none'});
    }
    return true; 
  }); 
    $("#newid").hover(function(){
    $(".block-bookoblock ul.menu").css("display","block");
    },function(){
    $(".block-bookoblock ul.menu").css("display","none");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `'#page:not(#newid)'` what are you trying to do with this?

Comment: so a left click within this div does not close the newly created menu block

Answer (score 0):

Your hover event only applies to `#newid` elements at the time it is called. To have it also apply to future objects, use the notation

```
$("#newid").on('hover', function(){ ...
```

Of course, you shouldn't have two objects of the same ID to begin with.

Comment: `hover()` is actually a shortcut for the 2 parameter version of `on()`, so this shouldn't make any difference without using delegation.

Comment: If I change `$("section.block-bookoblock").hover(function(){
    $(".block-bookoblock ul.menu").css("display","block");
    },function(){
    $(".block-bookoblock ul.menu").css("display","none");
  });`
to
`$("section.block-bookoblock").on ('hover', function(){
    $(".block-bookoblock ul.menu").css("display","block");
    },function(){
    $(".block-bookoblock ul.menu").css("display","none");
  });`

Comment: ...the hover event does not get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Try using delegation for your dynamically added content, like this:

```
$("body").on("hover", "#newid", function() { ... });
```

There seems to be several problems with your code though, a couple I see quickly:

`#page:not(#newid)` this is checking that the element with the ID of "page" does not have the ID of "newid" which doesn't make sense.

it looks like you could end up with several elements of the same id if the user clicks multiple times, without knowing your full context, perhaps you should be using a class and using delegation based on that class name?

Comment: #page:not(#newid) serves as a selector for all clicks outside of the newid div

Comment: your code suggestion also does not react on hovering over the original nor the cloned div